# Excel auto fill column by X+++..Y++..Z+

Tags: excel

[image: exl]

How do I autofill the values in between?

Comment: autofill numbers? so 1,2,3 then 2,3,4,5,6, then 3,4 ... ?

Comment: Judging from the image I think he wants 111 22222 33 444 5555 66 
Wondered about this problem myself not that long ago. I guess a macro can do it, but can it be done without?

Comment: If you double click the little black dot that appears in the lower right corner of the cell when you select A1 it will extend the 1's down to fill the gap, similarly for 2, 3, etc.. You'd just need one double click per number, not sure how many you ultimately have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to end up with

[image: simulate2]

use this `VBA`

```
Sub FillValues()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If IsEmpty(c) Then c = c.Offset(-1, 0)
    Next c
End Sub
```

hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to open VBE, then right click in the `Project Explorer` (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) 

and `Insert` » **`Module`**

then <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F8</kbd> to `View Macros` » select **`FillValues`**

to get

[image: autofill simulation]

use

```
Sub FillValues()
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Range("A1:A" & Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        If IsEmpty(c) Then c = c.Offset(-1, 0) +1
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: ERROR---    If IsEmpty(c) Then c

Answer (score 6):

Select Column A, `CTRL+G` -> `Blanks` -> `OK`
Type `=` press `UpArrow`, then press `CTRL+ENTER`

See [this link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/quickly-fill-blank-cells-in-excel/) for explanation. It is basically find all blanks and enter a formula to all of them.

**EDIT:** as @kurast pointed out for safety/sanity reasons select all and Copy and Paste Special as Values.

Comment: Oh. I see. Where were you all these years (the ones I've been doing [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17726882/330057))?

Comment: You have to copy and paste values for added safety, in case it is sorted.

Answer (score 5):

I've not found a great way to do this, ever. There's a not-great workaround I use from time to time:

1. Insert a column after `A`
2. Copy the first value over - so `B1: =A1`
3. Starting at B2, drag the formula of `B2: =IF(A2 = "", B1, A2)`
4. Copy `B:B`
5. Paste values into `A:A`
6. Delete column `B`

Comment: until I discovered the power of `CTRL+G` blanks, I was doing your way! :)

Answer (score 1):

Make another column to generate them for you. Insert a new column B, make `B1` = `A1`, then use this formula in `B2`:

```
=IF(A2="",B1+1,A2)
```

And drag it down; it will perform the logic you want.

Then you can copy column B, and `paste special values` -> `values` to "hard-code" the results.

---

Edit: I am not sure exactly what you mean by "auto-fill"; @corsiKa's formula will result in

```
11122222333444...
```

Mine will result in:

```
12323456345456...
```

Comment: hi i wants 111 22222 33 444 5555 66