# Copy data down a column if no two cells in the same row are blank

Tags: excel

I am not able to check if two rows are empty.

[image]
As you can see in my screen shot (upper part) I have a spreadsheet with 
`Unit Data` and `Value` as my columns. I would like to achieve the result shown in the lower part.

Currently I have the code which copies data until empty row occurs, but that doesn't fit my requirement. Please help in getting this macro built.

Comment: Do you want to use `VBA`?

Comment: Use a 3rd/new column to evaluate whether the Unit Data column is populated.  For example, if your data header "Unit Data" is in B1, copy this formula down column A (the new column, starting with A2): `=IF(B2<>"",B2,B1)`  You might want to tweak it a little to handle those rows that have no "Value" entry, but that's the gist of how I'd achieve your end result... w/out VBA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Excel auto fill column by X+++..Y++..Z+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726767/excel-auto-fill-column-by-x-y-z)

Answer (score 0):

Filter on ColumnB to select (Blanks) (only), insert `'` in the first blank in ColumnA and copy down to suit. Remove the filter, select ColumnA, HOME > Editing, Find & Select, Go To Special..., select Blanks (only), OK. <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>Up</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.